# Add variable string to datetime eg. 2 weeks

Tags: php

is it possible to add a variable string like '2 day, 2 weeks or even 4 hours' to a date time in PHP.

For example:

I have a date time like this: '2017-08-02 12:00'
now the user choose an interval like '4 hours or 2 weeks'
now the user choice should be added to the date time.

Is this possible?

I don't want the whole code, maybe just an advice how to do that.

thanks

Comment: You should check [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

Comment: You could format the user input into an [*interval spec*](http://php.net/manual/dateinterval.construct.php#refsect1-dateinterval.construct-parameters), eg `P2WT4H` and use it in `DateTime#add`

Comment: How is the user choice controlled? Is it just free text or are there specific fields they enter?

Comment: There are two select tags, one for the number eg. 1-24 and one for the name like week, hour, day

Comment: I think strtotime might be the right beginning. thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, use

```
$userDate = strtotime('2017-08-02 12:00:00');

echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('+4 hours', $userDate));
```

to get date after 4 hours

[Example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/13cd48f9e377f82b6b2dea58da50a1ae66b76f8a)

---

*Explanation*

[`strtotime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) converts about any English textual datetime description into a Unix timestamp. Most commonly it's used with actual date string or with difference string. E.g. `+5 months`, 'next Monday' and so on. It will return Unix timestamp - integer that represents how much seconds there is after 1970-01-01 (1970-01-01 00:00:00 is 0, 1970-01-01 00:01:00 is 60 and so on).

So in `strtotime('2017-08-02 12:00:00')` we convert date to integer for later use.

`strtotime('+4 hours', $userDate)` - here we use our date as "now" parameter (by default it's `time()`) and requesting to return timestamp after 4 hours.

`echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', ...);` - [`date`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) accepts format and Unix timestamp to convert from integer back to human readable text.

Comment: this works! thank you very much. But I want to understand it not just copy and paste. so I will read about it.

Comment: @Reebal I have added some explanation about answer

Comment: thank you, I appreciate it. Is it possible then to user it like: `strtotime($hours, $userData);` ?

Comment: @Reebal Yes, you can if `$hours` is valid string

Answer (score 2):

May be you are looking for this:
http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.modify.php

```
$date = new DateTime('2006-12-12');
$date->modify('+1 day');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

Answer (score 0):

For a datetime you can use the add method but you have to put in the correct code for the amount to add.

```
$my_date = new DateTime();

$addition = 4;

$my_new_date = $my_date->add(new DateInterval("P${addition}D"));

echo $my_new_date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Where addition is your variable that you want to add.